# Why do `gem install` and `add_runtime_dependency` install different versions?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Given that the gem [bundle](https://rubygems.org/gems/bundle)'s (note the missing 'r') only job is to install `bundler` as a dependency, why is the version being installed different?

```
root@0879914af1e6:/# gem install bundle --explain
Gems to install:
  bundle-0.0.1
  bundler-2.0.0.pre.1
root@0879914af1e6:/# gem install bundler --explain
Gems to install:
  bundler-1.17.1
```

Why does `gem install` seemingly default to stable packages whereas `add_runtime_dependency` (as seen in [bundle's gemspec](https://github.com/will/bundle/blob/master/bundle.gemspec)) doesn't?